# 4-velocity lowering index question

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, differentiation, notation

The 4-velocity in contravariant form is given by
$$V^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$$
for some general co-ordinates $x^\mu$ and proper time $\tau$.

Is the 4-velocity in covariant form given by

$$V_\nu=V^\mu g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{dx_\nu}{d\tau}?$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In the context of general relativity these are better understood when you consider their transformations!

Comment: So $V_\nu=dx_\nu/d\tau$ is the correct notation?

Comment: I wouldn't say "correct", since it's notation. It is what we usually use though.

Comment: Ok - great. I was worried that I was somehow assuming that $g_{\mu\nu}$ could go inside the $\tau$ differential

Comment: I would say it is incorrect as explained in comments [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525963/2451). It is at best confusing/misleading notation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. However, the last term is a bit 'icky' because it looks like
$$
\frac{dx_\nu}{d\tau} = \frac{d}{d\tau} x_\nu
$$
while what is actually meant is
$$
\frac{dx_\nu}{d\tau} = \left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)_\nu
$$
It doesn't really make sense to 'lower' the index of a coordinate of the base manifold. However, while I wouldn't recommend it, I think I've seen other people use that notation as well.